# PHP unset vs array_pop?

Tags: php, arrays, unset

If I want to remove the last element of an array, I can use either of these two code:

1. [`array_pop($array);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) (the return value is not used)
2. [`unset($array[count($array) -1]);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Is there any performance or semantic difference between them?

If not, which is preferred?

Comment: array_pop returns the popped element.

Comment: I would think pop would be faster because there is no count call or subtraction going on. But i mean thats a micro optimization youll probably never notice. I think pop is more readable and more "understandable at a glance".

Comment: @prodigitalson if your array of a size that such a difference would be ever noticeable - think of reducing the array size. It will be real optimization, unlike just a feeling of it.

Comment: `unset($array[count($array) -1]);` will not work with associative arrays, or enumerated arrays where there are gaps in the enumeration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`unset` is no good if you need to "do" anything with the removed value (unless you have previously assigned it to something elsewhere) as it does not return anything, whereas `array_pop` will give you the thing that was the last item.

The `unset` option you have provided *may* be marginally less performant since you are counting the length of the array and performing some math on it, but I expect the difference, if any, is negligible.

As others have said, the above is true if your array is numerical and contiguous, however if you array is not structured like this, stuff gets complicated

For example:

```
<?php
$pop = $unset = array(
  1 => "a",
  3 => "b",
  0 => "c"
);

array_pop($pop);

// array looks like this:
//  1 => "a", 3 => "b"

$count = count($unset) - 1;
unset($count);
// array looks like this because there is no item with index "2"
//  1 => "a", 3 => "b", 0 => "c"
```

Answer (score 10):

`array_pop($array)` removes the last element of `$array`.

`unset($array[count($array) -1]);` removes the element at index `count($array) -1`. This element is not neccesarily the last element of the array.

Consider `$array = array(0 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 1 => 'baz')`. In this case , `$array[1]` is the last element. The code

```
foreach (array(0 => "foo", 2 => "bar", 1 => "baz") as $key => $value)
  echo "$key => $value\n";
```

prints

> ```
> 0 => foo
> 2 => bar
> 1 => baz
> ```

Moreover, an element at index `count($array) -1` might not even exist. There can be gaps in the set of indices and integer indices can be mixed with string indices.

Answer (score 5):

The return values are different.  `array_pop` returns the last element, while `unset` doesn't return anything.

For simply removing the last element, `array_pop` would be better because you don't need to execute `count($array)-1`, and it is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: @Lix, yes I mean that point was pretty explicit.. you see the semicolon shows that *that* is the complete statement......

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

Firstly, the `unset()` option will only work for numerical, contiguous arrays. If your array contains elements that are not numerical, or has any gaps in its numerical sequence, then the `unset()` call will get the incorrect value from `count()` and will fail.

Secondly, assuming your array is numerical and contiguous, there is still a difference:

`array_pop()` will also give you back the value of the popped element as a return value. `unset()` will not do this.

So if you need to keep using the data, use `array_pop()`.

If you don't need to keep the value, then no, it probably doesn't matter too much which one you use, I suspect that `array_pop()` may be faster (due to not needing to call `count()`), but I haven't checked, and to be honest, unless you're doing thousands of calls, the difference will be negligible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the obvious differences in call syntax and return value...

`array_pop` always pops whatever is last.
Your `count - 1` unsets an element by its numeric id, which only works as you expect it to if all elements are *continuously numerically indexed*.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, using a bit of existing code that gets called a bit over 2000 times in a run, I put in a $whatevers[]=$whatever (a parameter value) at the top and and array_pop($whatevers) at the bottom.

The function calls itself recursively down to about 7 or 8 levels and (of course) I made $whatevers static so the array grew and shrunk.

The result? The difference between this code in and commented out was unmeasurable down to 100ths of a second on a windows 7 laptop. It varied a fair bit because of other things, but over lots of runs the difference in the averages was meaningless.

The performance overhead of array_pop() just isn't worth a second thought and though unset might be theoretically faster, nobody will ever be able to detect the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned - their functionality is the same, bar the return value from `array_pop`. However, it's also worth mentioning the possible performance issue of the `unset` method on a large array due to the `count()` call.

As Oswald mentions, it is also worth noting that `unset()` will only be working as expected on numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference

array_pop() will also return removed element eg: last element, and

unset() will not return any thing

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer unset() but you call count() which can consume performance.

An alternative choice is array_slice(array, offset, length, preserve_keys) :

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, -1, true);
```

Comment: No no this creates a new array, that's not what I want.

Comment: I forgot the return value to rewrite the array

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration to take into account is that if after deleting the last item you push a new element, you get different results in which the index the new element is placed at:

#### unset

```
php > $a = [1,2,3];
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
php > unset($a[2]);
php > var_dump($a);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
php > $a[] = 5;
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(5)
}
```

As you see, the new element is placed at index `3` instead of `2`.

#### array_pop

```
php > $a = [1,2,3];
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
php > array_pop($a);
php > var_dump($a);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
php > $a[] = 5;
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Now the new element is placed at index `2`. Maybe this is the most desirable behaviour.